# How deserialize avro records without schema

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am learning avro schema.

In my scenario, in the sender side, it encodes an avro record with a specific schema, and hope record contains schema and user data, then sender sends this record to receiver side.

In the receiver side, for some reason, it doesn't have schema.

The question is
(1) Is it possible for sender side to encode a record and the record contains schema ? If yes, how to do that? Do you have any example code to share it?

(2) Could receiver side extract schema from record ? If yes, how to do that? Please  share your example.